# How to fix it my password_hash to be valid

Tags: php, password-hash

Why invallid?

```
// password_hash
$get_pass= $_POST['pass'];
$pass = password_hash($get_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// password_verify
$sql = $con->query("SELECT name,pass FROM tb_user WHERE name = 'MRD'");
$show= $sql->fetch_assoc();
$pass = $show['pass'];

if (password_verify("321321", $pass)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

In my output "Invalid password, how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that the password is 321321? How about printing a few things out, e.g. `$pass` to make sure that you are getting a result from the database.

Comment: Is your database field long enough to store the hash?

Comment: I use Varchar 35, how much do I have to at least, and but is my code correct?